# Delivery price depending on order value with multiple thresholds

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

Suppose we purchase N products from different vendors. We have many suppliers, but not all products are available from every supplier. The price for each product is known to each retailer, unless the product is not available there. There is also a shipping fee for each seller. The shipping fee is payable only once for all orders from a given supplier. It may also be subject to special restrictions, e.g. if the total order value exceeds 179USD, shipping is free, otherwise shipping is 15.99 USD or it is impossible if it does not meet the minimum order value, e.g. 100 USD. The shipping price for each seller may vary. Based on the products selected and the pricing and shipping information from different vendors, how can we optimize the total cost (product price + shipping) for the entire product cart, assuming we always want to buy all products?

Currently, I can solve this problem for fixed delivery costs for each supplier, but I cannot cope with adding conditional constraints taking into account the value of the order with a given supplier, e.g .:

- order> = 179 PLN = free delivery
- order <179 PLN AND order> = 100 PLN = delivery 15.99 PLN
- minimum order = PLN 100 (below this amount, the order is not possible with the given supplier.

As for the structure of data on delivery costs, the 'key' means the minimum amount from which the 'value', i.e. delivery cost, is met for a given supplier. If the cost of a product under 'product_prices' for a given supplier is 99999999, it means that the product is not available from them. Below is the example data:

```
 'delivery_prices': {
    'supplier1': {
      100: 14.9,
    },
    'supplier2': {
      0: 19.99,
      179: 0,
    },
    'supplier3': {
      100: 15,
      200: 10,
      250: 0,
    },
  }
```

Here is my optimization code as for now:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po

solver = po.SolverFactory('glpk')

def optimization_problem(input_data, solver):
    model = pe.ConcreteModel("All products filled")

    # sets
    model.I = pe.Set(initialize=input_data['supplier_names'])
    model.J = pe.Set(initialize=input_data['product_names'])

    # parameters
    model.s = pe.Param(model.I, initialize=input_data['supplier_stock'])
    model.d = pe.Param(model.J, initialize=input_data['demand'])
    model.f = pe.Param(model.I, initialize=input_data['delivery_prices'])
    model.c = pe.Param(model.I, model.J, initialize=input_data['product_prices'])

    # variables
    model.x = pe.Var(model.I, model.J, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals)
    model.y = pe.Var(model.I, domain=pe.Binary) # product quantity for given suppliersupplier

    # constraints
    # if sum 
    def con_satisfaction(model, j):
        return sum(model.x[i, j] for i in model.I) >= model.d[j]
    model.con_satisfaction = pe.Constraint(model.J, rule=con_satisfaction)

    def con_transportation(model, i):
        return sum(model.x[i, j] for j in model.J) <= model.s[i] * model.y[i]
    model.con_transportation = pe.Constraint(model.I, rule=con_transportation)

    # objective
    def obj_min_cost(model):
        return sum(model.f[i] * model.y[i] for i in model.I)\
            + sum(model.c[i, j] * model.x[i, j] for i in model.I for j in model.J)
    model.obj_min_cost = pe.Objective(sense=pe.minimize, rule=obj_min_cost)
    
    solver.solve(model)

    products_distribution = { key: value for key, value in model.x.extract_values().items() if value > 0}
    products_suppliers = list(set([product[0] for product in products_distribution.keys()]))
    suppliers_delivery_prices = {supplier:price for supplier, price in input_data['delivery_prices'].items() if supplier in products_suppliers}
    
    return (model.obj_min_cost(), products_suppliers, suppliers_delivery_prices, products_distribution)


# EXECUTE FUNCTION
optimization_problem(example_dataset, solver)
```

Does anyone have any guidance how to incorporate conditional delivery prices?

Comment: You're going to have to set up a mildly complex set of binary variables for each supplier to denote which "tier" you are in for that supplier, and link that binary variable, indexed by "tier" to the amount purchased from that supplier.

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for the response, but how about putting up the constraint with minimal order as well, i.e. for supplier 1 and supplier 3 - if the total order is below 100, it cannot be realised. Additionally, would you be able to guide me a little bit more with the code for your suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with the introduction of a binary variable, indexed by supplier and tier.  Also added are 2 constraints to link the tier to the lower and upper bounds on qty from a supplier (linking constraints).

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')

s1, s2 = 'supplier 1', 'supplier 2'
p1, p2 = 'bike', 'cellphone'

# some fake data
input_data = {  'supplier_names'    : [s1, s2],
                'product_names'     : [p1, p2],
                'supplier_stock'    : {(s1, p1): 1000, (s1, p2): 500, (s2, p1): 700, (s2, p2): 400},
                'demand'            : {p1: 50, p2: 80},
                'product_prices'    : {(s1, p1): 100, (s1, p2): 150, (s2, p1): 90, (s2, p2): 160}
                }
max_products = 10000 # some reasonable large "big M" upper bound on the total number of products from a supplier
penalty = 10000  # some reasonably large penalty...

                    # supplier    tier                 (qty, price)
delivery_prices = {   s1:        {'below min'   :      (0, penalty),    # <100 N/A, use penalty
                                  '1A'          :      (100, 19.99),
                                  '1B'          :      (200, 0.00)},    
                      s2:        {'regular'     :      (0, 25.00),
                                  'free'        :      (150, 0.00)} }

# make a convenience set of all the tier label possiblities accross all suppliers...
all_tiers = set()
for k in delivery_prices:
    all_tiers.update(set(delivery_prices[k].keys()))

model = pe.ConcreteModel("All products filled")

# sets
model.suppliers = pe.Set(initialize=input_data['supplier_names'])
model.products = pe.Set(initialize=input_data['product_names'])
model.tiers = pe.Set(initialize=list(all_tiers))
model.supplier_tiers = pe.Set(within=model.suppliers * model.tiers, initialize={(s,t) for s in delivery_prices
                                for t in delivery_prices[s]})

# parameters
model.s = pe.Param(model.suppliers, model.products, initialize=input_data['supplier_stock'])
model.d = pe.Param(model.products, initialize=input_data['demand'])
model.c = pe.Param(model.suppliers, model.products, initialize=input_data['product_prices'])

# variables
model.x = pe.Var(model.suppliers, model.products, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals) # product quantity for given suppliersupplier
model.y = pe.Var(model.supplier_tiers, domain=pe.Binary)       # buy from supplier s at tier t 


# constraints

# link quantity to supplier tier LB
def tier(model, supplier, tier):
    return sum(model.x[supplier, p] for p in model.products) >= model.y[supplier, tier]*delivery_prices[supplier][tier][0]
model.tier_min = pe.Constraint(model.supplier_tiers, rule=tier)

# link quantity to supplier UB...  this forces selection of some tier to get anything from supplier
def upper(model, supplier):
    return sum(model.x[supplier, p] for p in model.products) <= sum(model.y[supplier, tier] for tier in model.tiers
        if (supplier, tier) in model.supplier_tiers) * max_products
model.upper_bound = pe.Constraint(model.suppliers, rule=upper)

# meet demand
def demand(model, product):
    return sum(model.x[supplier, product] for supplier in model.suppliers) >= model.d[product]
model.demand = pe.Constraint(model.products, rule=demand)


# objective
def obj_min_cost(model):
    return sum(model.x[s, p] * model.c[s, p] for s in model.suppliers for p in model.products) + \
    sum(model.y[s, t] * delivery_prices[s][t][1] for s,t in model.supplier_tiers)
model.obj_min_cost = pe.Objective(sense=pe.minimize, rule=obj_min_cost)

result = solver.solve(model)
print(result)
model.display()

# products_distribution = { key: value for key, value in model.x.extract_values().items() if value > 0}
# products_suppliers = list(set([product[0] for product in products_distribution.keys()]))
# suppliers_delivery_prices = {supplier:price for supplier, price in input_data['delivery_prices'].items() if supplier in products_suppliers}
```